# how to solve a xor system of boolean equations?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 boolean equations:

```
> F=~I5+I1*I2*I3*I4 

> F_A1=~I5+~(I3*I4)
```

And I would make to make XOR between them, but this is what I get:

```
>> xor(F, F_A1)

ans =

(~I5) + I1*I2*I3*I4 xor (~I5) + (~I3*I4)
```

Where's the error ?

Comment: So, you are getting a symbolic expression as the result, do you need a boolean result instead (e.g. true or false)? Can you show how you defined or obtained the variables in your expression?

Comment: >> syms I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6 . What I want is the resultant equation

Answer (score 0):

You declared the symbolic variables and then performed some calculations. Since the variables do not have any value assigned to them the symbolic toolbox is simply returning you the expression (which is the correct behavior). You must substitute values for the variables to get a numerical (boolean in your case) result. Use the function [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html?searchHighlight=subs).
In your case you want multiple substitutions. You may want to simplify your result as well. It is not clear from your questions what exactly you are looking for. If you just want a numerical answer you don't need the symbolic variables, just regular boolean variables will do.

Comment: I just want Matlab to solve that XOR equation, I want to have the expression depending on the variables I1, I2, I3 ...

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by solve: when you solve an equation you normally try to solve for a specific variable, e.g. x + 2 = 0, solved for x, yields x = - 2. MATLAB cannot solve the equation because none of the variables have a value assigned. In fact that is an expression, not an equation (there is no '= something'). Perhaps you would like matlab to simplify that expression?

Comment: for example: A XOR B => (A*~B)+(~A*B). How can I make that operation in matlab? if I write xor(a,b) look what I get: 
 >> xor(a,b)
 
ans =
 
a xor b

Comment: A computer algebra system (CAS) cannot guess what is the form of an expression that we human like better. Sometimes is the shortest expression, other times is an expanded version. You need to tell this explicitly. In this case the internal representation is simply keeping the xor operator because it results in the shortest form of the expression (which is good, because it is simpler to work with for successive calculations). There is also an `expand` function, although I have never tried it on boolean variables. You could try that.

Comment: I get it. And is it possible to get the truth table of that expression?

Comment: That is certainly possible; to get the truth table there are two approaches: generate all possible assignments of I1,.. I5 variables (2^5=32 combinations), then use a for loop to substitute one at a time and simplify the expression. An even faster method would be to use regular (non-symbolic) variables and print all combinations in a similar manner. The latter is better because you don't really need the overhead of dealing with symbolic math..